# Why do I get 2 different values in C

Tags: c

When I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int hi, hello;

  hi = 1;
  hello = 100;

  printf("%d and %d", &hi, &hello);

  printf("\nPress any key to exit...");
  getch();
}
```

It prints:

```
2358876 and 2358872

Press any key to exit
```

But when I define the variables `hi` and `hello` separately as integers it does what it should. Why does it print these weird numbers?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you get two different values?

Comment: Please compile your code with all warnings turned on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
printf("%d and %d", &hi, &hello);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d and %d", hi, hello);
```

You want to print the *values* of the variables, not their addresses.

And if you did want to print their addresses, you'd need to use `%p` and convert the addresses to `void*`:

```
printf("address of hi is %p\n", (void*)&hi);
```

(You may have been confused by the fact that `scanf` requires addresses for the values it reads.)

You say that you get the correct behavior if you "define the variables hi and hello seperately as integers". I don't know what you mean; if you use `&hi` and `&hello` in your `printf` call, you're always going to get weird values.

Comment: Aha thank you ;) I'm still learning the basics of C, and it looked really weird to me xD

Answer (score 1):

You are printing not the value of the variables, but the addresses by using "&" before hi and hello. 
 
To print the values you must write this: 
    `printf("%d and %d", hi, hello);`

Answer (score 1):

It is giving right answer...

`&` is used to specify address...

As two variables can't have same address it will show different for every variable

If you want a value to be printed don't specify & in printing.

for eg

```
printf("%d",hi);    // will give you 1

printf("%d",&hi);   // Will always gives you different number every time on every machine

// It is showing address where the actual value of the variable hi is stored..
```